# Extract Multiple Numbers from a String in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, regex, data-extraction

I have the following data in Excel

```
Work_Experience
6 Year(s) 1 Month(s)
12 Year(s) 11 Month(s)
10 Year(s) 10 Month(s)
10 Year(s) 2 Month(s)
2 Year(s) 12 Month(s)
```

Now I want that in Python there should be two extra columns generated as Output which have # of Years (Digit) in Column B and # of Months (Digit) in Column C like the Output shown below

```
Work_Experience       Year  Month
6 Year(s) 1 Month(s)     6      1
12 Year(s) 11 Month(s)  12     11
10 Year(s) 10 Month(s)  10     10
10 Year(s) 2 Month(s)   10      2
2 Year(s) 12 Month(s)    2     12
```

I Tried the following Code Below

```
Test[['Year','Month']] = Test['Work_Experience'].str.extract(\(\d+)(\d+))
```

it's showing SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: please provide your examples as **text**, images are not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['Year', 'Month']] = (df['Work_Experience']
                         .str.extract('(\d+)\s*Year.*?(\d+)\s*Month')
                         .astype(int)
                         )
```

Output:

```
          Work_Experience Year Month
0    6 Year(s) 1 Month(s)    6     1
1  12 Year(s) 11 Month(s)   12    11
2  10 Year(s) 10 Month(s)   10    10
3   10 Year(s) 2 Month(s)   10     2
4   2 Year(s) 12 Month(s)    2    12
```

##### alternative

If you want an alternative that extracts the names in any order and automatically assigns the next word as column name:

```
df = df.join(df['Work_Experience']
 .str.extractall('(\d+)\s*(\w+)')
 .droplevel(1)
 .pivot(columns=1, values=0).astype(int)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `\(\d+)(\d+)` starts with matching a literal parenthesis `\(` in `\(\d+)` but then has an unclosed (unescaped) parenthesis after it that has a different meaning. There are also characters in between the digits that are not matched.

**Note** that you have to put the regex between quotes when using `str.extract`

If you want to combine matching the parenthesis and the groupings of the digits:

```
\b(\d+)\s+Year\(s\)\s+(\d+)\s+Month\(s\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `\s+Year\(s\)\s+` Match `Year(s)` between 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 2
- `\s+Month\(s\) Match 1+ whitspace chars and` Month(s)`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/600huQ/1).

```
Test[['Year', 'Month']] = Test['Work_Experience'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)\s+Year\(s\)\s+(\d+)\s+Month\(s\)')
print(Test)
```

Output

```
          Work_Experience Year Month
0    6 Year(s) 1 Month(s)    6     1
1  12 Year(s) 11 Month(s)   12    11
2  10 Year(s) 10 Month(s)   10    10
3   10 Year(s) 2 Month(s)   10     2
4   2 Year(s) 12 Month(s)    2    12
```